# Issue with SQLite database writing/updating a record from one thread while another is doing a delete

Tags: .net, sqlite, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android application and using SQLite for the db (SQLite.Net from NuGet). I am having an issue with a call to update a single row in a table where it waits/blocks for sometimes up to 2 minutes before it finishes.

I have a timer/thread that does some db operations on the same table as a form of cleanup/syncronization of data which calls another method (in the same class) to do some delete and insert of data.

It is important to note that all of my data methods create their own connections in a using block. There seems to be debate about this but per the Microsoft docs, this is the recommended approach.

I think my delay happens when I try to do an update using the first method while the second method is busy doing some delete and inserts.

I do have WAL enabled and am not running in a transaction. The question is, does SQLite have table level locking by default, where it will block the first method while another method is doing some delete or inserts? If so, does it do this even if it comes from two different connections too?

If this is the case, it seems that the blocking is not releasing right away. Is there a way to force things to happen faster? I also suspect that WAL could be contributing to the issue if it blocks until WAL does a checkpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Only one connection can write to a database at a time.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you! So, are you suggesting that if one method opens the connection in a using block and another method comes along and opens a connection, it will allow the other method to open the connection BUT not do a read or write until the first connection is closed? And, if that is true, since I am opening connections in a using block, I have to wait for the GC to dispose/close the connection which could explain delays? Also, where does the blocking happen, on the call to Execute?

Comment: Since you're using WAL mode instead of the normal journal, a connection with a write lock doesn't block readers. See https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html and https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html for details. Oh and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: @Shawn Thanks again for the help and links. I read through them and had actually read the wal one before. So, it seems like writers don't block readers like you said and is in the docs. However, I am still trying to figure out my delay. AS i was explaining, I actually have two writers in my case. So, one is going to get blocked, which I understand. But, the blocked writer seems to take a long time sometimes to finish its write when I think the first one should be done. I am thinking that something is holding the lock on the first writer longer than it should.

Comment: I am guessing that the using statement could do that. I am not explicitly calling close and instead relying on the using statement to close the connection but I guess this could take a while since it is dependent on the GC. Maybe I should explicitly call close in a finally block to force the lock to release and let the second one write?

Comment: The occasional longer time could be caused by checkpointing the WAL back to the main database file. I don't know how using works in C#.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203637/discussion-between-michael-bedford-and-shawn).

Comment: @Michael, any update?Have you solved your issue now?